# Controller router error to render ejs page

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, ejs, router

I have included correct code but still getting error how can I make this work below is the code of each file

inde.controller.js file

```
function renderIndex(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
  }
  
  module.exports = {
    renderIndex 
  };
```

index.js file

```
console.log()
//Intialise a router object using express framework assigned to varibale indexRouter.
const express = require('express')
const indexController = require('../controllers/index.controller');
const indexRouter = express.Router()

router.get('/', indexController.renderIndex)

//export the module Router
module.exports = indexRouter;
console.log()
```

app.js file

```
//where I define the application route, middleware, request, validation

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const port= process.env.PORT || 3000;
const path = require('path');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const { urlencoded } = require("body-parser");
const req = require("express/lib/request");
const res = require("express/lib/response");
//creates route that allows access to page includes request and reponse variable
const router = express.Router()
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

require('dotenv').config()

//body parser will help us parse json data through forms
//parsing middle ware 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
//parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//tells the application what directorty view is in
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'src/views'));
//tells the application the engine being used
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/css',express.static(__dirname + 'public/css'));
app.use('/img',express.static(__dirname + 'public/img'));


app.use(expressLayouts);
//layouts will direct everypage in out application here so that it will automatically set beginning html and code where needed
app.set('layout','./layouts/layouts');
//static files
//tells application where stylesheets, html, js files are gonna be.
app.use(express.static('public'));
//tells application to get forms and access them inside request variable inside post method.
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));

//middleware handles request that not being handled
//app.use((req, res, next) => {
    //console.log(`Received ${req.method} request for ${req.url}`);
    //next();
 // });

 //router use
app.use('/index', indexRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

expecting it to render the index.ejs file to ui but not getting this result if anyone can help or point in the right direction would really appreciate

Comment: "_Not getting this result_" - So what result are you getting? Any error messages in Node or in the client?

Comment: error in the client it says cannot get/index

Comment: that is the error message that comes up when I start the serve 'cannot get/index' on the client side @JDB

Comment: Do you mean `Cannot GET /index.html`? Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69966345/211627

Comment: @JDB the extension of file is index.ejs, ejs is the express template that allows me to write my html code in this template, I have stored all my ejs files inside a views folder

Comment: however the error im still getting is, Cannot get/index.ejs I don't know why because I have routed everything properly @JDB

Comment: I'm no expert and there may be a use I'm not familiar with, but when I use `.ejs` it is always compiled into an `.html` file. Why are you trying to request a `.ejs` file in the client?

Comment: im requesting because its what contains the html for the client side @JDB